# I ran into dependency problem with building catkin_ws for kitti_to_rosbag package

Tags: rosbag, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am provided with a kitti dataset at  http://kitti.is.tue.mpg.de/kitti/raw_data/2011_09_26_drive_0001/2011_09_26_drive_0001_extract.zip. I have to convert this dataset into rosbag using the package https://github.com/ethz-asl/kitti_to_rosbag. This package require dependencies provided in the link https://github.com/ethz-asl/kitti_to_rosbag/blob/master/kitti_to_rosbag/package.xml. After cloning kitti_to_rosbag package into my ~/cw/src and performing catkin_make in my catkin workspace produces the following error:

> CMake Error at kitti_to_rosbag/kitti_to_rosbag/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
> By not providing "Findcatkin_simple.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
> project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
> "catkin_simple", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin_simple" with any
> of the following names:         catkin_simpleConfig.cmake     and
> catkin_simple-config.cmake

I followed the following commands:

> cd ~/cw/src

> git clone https://github.com/ethz-asl/kitti_to_rosbag

> cd ..

> catkin_make

In an attempt to rectify this error, I also cloned all dependent packages(catkin_simple, cv_bridge, eigen_checks ...) provided in the package.xml for kitti_to_rosbag into my catkin/src folder. However, it gives this error

> No rule to make target '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgflags.so', needed by '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libeigen_checks.so

Any help would be greatly appreciated . Having a deadline for this task, I am open to alternative packages/methods.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264817/i-ran-into-dependency-problem-with-building-catkin_ws-for-kitti_to_rosbag-package/) by [Cheema](https://answers.ros.org/users/30898/cheema/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quick answer since you're in a hurry:

It looks like you're missing dependencies. Did you install them? Try to install them with `rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y -r` from your catkin_ws folder.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cheema](https://answers.ros.org/users/30898/cheema/) on 2017-06-26**:
After rosdep command and sourcing.It still gives the following error:
No rule to make target '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgflags.so', needed by '/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libeigen_checks.so
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1694: recipe for target 'eigen_checks/CMakeFiles/eigen_checks.dir/all' failed

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-27**:
Looks like you need to install gflags and eigen too.

**Comment by [Cheema](https://answers.ros.org/users/30898/cheema/) on 2017-06-27**:
I cloned gflags and eigen into my ~/catkin_ws/src. Is it the right way to"install" these packages?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-27**:
No. Install them with apt.